# How to get coworkers to volunteer for team building tasks at work?

Tags: india, team-building

Suppose I am organizing a birthday party for a coworker. This is not an official event. The team as a whole agreed to do it on every coworker's birthday.

Someone needs to get a cake (and some other things) from the shop. I would like one of my coworkers<sup>1</sup> to volunteer, because it is not practical for me to go to the shop every time. The volunteer won't *pay* for the cake.

I want to avoid:

- Choosing a "volunteer" due to the [Got Volunteered](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GotVolunteered) issues. (warning: tvtropes)
- Trickery like "who likes ice cream?"<sup>2</sup> because it makes the "chosen one" feel stupid.
- Draw of lots, Rock Paper Scissors, etc. because it makes a mountain out of a molehill.
- "Who is getting the cake?" due to [Diffusion of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility).

How can I get someone to volunteer for such unofficial team building tasks while avoiding creating any negative vibes in the team?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not the team manager, but the most senior team member, which makes me the "ex officio" organizer for these fun events.

<sup>2</sup> Whoever raises their hand or says "me" first is chosen as the volunteer.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly asking any of your coworkers to get the cake?

Comment: @TheRealLester Yes, that leads to the first bullet in my avoid list.

Comment: I think the reasons you give show why, in most offices, the birthday-haver brings the cake. It‘s just easier that way because anyone can choose if and how to participate.

Comment: @Joe Stevens I don't know about how it is done in most offices, but in my culture, making the birthday boy/girl arrange for his/her own birthday party is not acceptable.

Comment: you WANT them to VOLUNTEER?

Comment: Does it _have to be_ the juniors? It sounds like you want them to do it because their time is cheaper. If they are trainees, that's a common joke in many countries and volunteering them is probably not considered bad (but still wrong!). I've always just asked the people I mentored if they would like to help me with organising something. Usually they did, and would then either pick their own tasks or simply defer to delegation and happily execute.

Comment: the tvtropes page you link to begins "A dirty, dangerous, and/or difficult job needs to get done, and nobody wants to do it". Perhaps what @TheRealLester is asking is, are you even *in* that situation? Maybe, just maybe, someone actually wants to go to the cake shop?

Comment: @simbabque There are no such sinister motives, it is a fun event. The word "junior" was just used to describe the work relationship, but since that caused some controversy, I got rid of it altogether.

Comment: @L.Dutch No, I would like *someone* to volunteer, because if everyone waits for someone else to volunteer, then nobody volunteers. I have now incorporated "Diffusion of responsibility" into the question.

Comment: I think your only option is to make either the event or the job so valuable that no one would turn down an opportunity to hang out at "work".  For example if you gave bonuses to attendees; or, if the pay was greatly above market value.  Failing those things, you have to let people say "no" to things you consider fun.

Comment: @PeteB. Except that the team as a whole agreed to the fun event. I was not involved in that decision at all, I just went with the flow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've implemented similar programs in a few organizations with the following approach:

If you want to participate in birthday celebrations, you add your name to a list. The list is sorted by birthday.

When someone's birthday is approaching, the *next* person on the list is responsible for the arrangements (picking up the cake or other supplies). The birthday person specifies their preference (they like chocolate cake or whatever) and the next-in-line simply executes.

This way, people can "opt in" to participating, which brings with it both the celebration of their own birthday, and some automatic delegation of responsibility. You're also encouraging team communication, since people will be talking to each other about what they like.

Payment can be arranged separately (ie the company foots the bill, or some higher-up) or it can be integrated, if the team is receptive and the company won't pick up the tab.

If there are willing participants who are physically unable to participate (ie ride a bicycle to work, or otherwise can't transport a cake), they could arrange to have someone help them, or they could purchase the cake or other goodies from a service that delivered - even in my small city, there are lots of bakeries and grocers who deliver.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. :) Good answer.

Comment: I've been waiting for the "who likes ice cream" question for days!

Comment: To clarify: the birthday person picks, the next-in-line simply executes. I will edit that in to the answer. Everyone gets what they want, everyone helps, everyone has some (albeit) minor communication with a "random" other person (in order to learn their preferences). I've done this where the staffers pay, and other places where the company (or some upper-level manager) pays.

Comment: This is a bad idea imo. How do you handle people who want to participate but can't because they don't have a car? Or travel to work through means that makes picking up the cake and other items very difficult? Honestly if you are leaving people out because they don't want to be responsible for  getting items for the event that sounds like breaking down teamwork.

Comment: @JoeW that's a good point, I've never come across that sort of situation on any of my teams hence my answer doesn't address it. I'd think that if there were a lot of people who wanted to participate but had no way of physically getting a cake, you'd find a way to accommodate it (they could double up with someone else. They could order something from a vendor that delivered - many groceries and bakeries in my city deliver). I will edit these ideas into my answer. Do you have a better suggestion for a method that could deal with that issue? Maybe you could post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer right now but another issue I would have with this (couldn't word it properly last night) is that I would consider this being voluntold as personally I wouldn't care if there was or wasn't a birthday celebration at work but being told I have to be willing to volunteer to take part would be offsetting for me.

Comment: @JoeW You're not "being told" anything. It's presented more like, "hey, come sign up if you want to help celebrate each other's birthdays!" People have the opportunity to decide if they want to participate or not (in essence: volunteer). No one is being told to. Voluntold would be, "You all must go buy cakes." IME (having done this at multiple employers over maybe 15+ years), no one has a problem with "volunteering," people are generally happy to help pitch in and celebrate each other's birthdays. Everyone on the team eats the cakes anyways, no one's being forced out of the actual celebration.

Comment: The way I read it is if you want to participate in the celebration you have to also participate in the setup as well which means people have to chose if they want to be left out of the event or not.

Comment: Everyone eats cake. People who want cake on their birthdays (versus only eating it on others') volunteer to help get cake for other people. Again, I've been doing this approach for a very long time across multiple employers with well over 100 people having participated, and I've never had even a hint of any negative response from anyone. The beauty of this approach is that people are generally *happy* to help get each other cake. You seem really stuck on worrying about this upsetting people, which it never has. If you have a better idea I'd suggest you post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that fundamentally volunteering has to be their own idea and if they aren't the sort to step up without being prompted then the closest you are likely to get is to have a meeting/email chain/IM chat/whatever about organizing the party and ask the question to the group in a general way. eg:

> I'll sort out the cookies, who can go to the bakery and get the cake?

and hope that someone volunteers at this point. If no-one does then it's either nominate someone (slightly tricky as you aren't a manager, you'd still need to *ask* if they mind doing it really) or do it yourself.

Since this is a recurring situation if you repeat the above often enough then people will likely get the cue and start doing it without being prompted - unless the task is particularly onerous of course.

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose I am organizing a birthday party for a coworker. This is not an official event. The team as a whole agreed to do it on every coworker's birthday. [...] How can I get someone to volunteer for such unofficial team building tasks while avoiding creating any negative vibes in the team?

If this is an *unofficial* even, plus *the whole team* agreed on it, and you are the *unofficial organizer* I think you are in a position to **just delegate tasks** to the others. Sometimes having *[too many cooks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/too_many_cooks_spoil_the_broth)* can make organizing these things more difficult.

Take the tasks to be done, divide them as equally as possible, and assign them to some coworkers. Don't forget to *assign yourself some tasks as well*, so they don't think you might be taking advantage.

Everybody agreed on it, so if they are complaining now (which they shouldn't) then they are free to refrain from participating on the event. Sometimes, to avoid those possible pitfalls you mention, it is better to just take the lead and assertively phrase your request, something like this perhaps:

> Ok, guys. I worked on a list of things we need for Mike's B-day party, so I'm going to need everybody's cooperation to carry this out. Joe, please go buy a cake from the store, one you think we would all like. Sarah, I need you to please go and grab some beers, a few six-pack would suffice. [...] while you are at it, I'll go look for a cool [piñata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C3%B1ata) and some snacks to eat. Here is the money guys (*gives money*), see you later.

This will spare you all the hassle of *getting* people to *volunteer* (harder than true volunteering spirit), and will be polite enough for anybody that is not a party-popper or lazy to agree on doing.

Answer (score 2):

> because it is not practical for me to go to the shop every time

Ask who has a shop or bakery on his route or who can do that with the least detour. Rotating through everybody is an obvious idea but depending on how you all get to work there is a good chance to find one or more people who CAN do that with minimal effort and - very important - who WANT to do that. So asking is better than selecting.

For example you can hardly bring a cake by bike, it's possible by public transport and really easy by car.
Perhaps somebody goes to the bakery in the morning anyway and doesn't feel having a problem to pick up a cake by the way. Or he/she only needs to stop or drive a short way extra, whild the other one who would be "next" has much more trouble with a shop in the morning.
Then another possibility is to take the cake home from the usual shopping and bring it to the office on the next day.

> I would like one of my junior1 coworkers to volunteer

Since WANTING to do that is important to keep everybody happy, you shouldn't select those people by rank.

Comment: Incidentally: You can most certainly bring a cake by bike (I've done it). You either pick a robust cake (such as fruit cake or pound cake), or you get a handy cake container box to transport it safely on your luggage carrier :-).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inconveniencing people, buy all the stuff online and ask for delivery at your place.  You will arrange for it to be delivered around early morning time, so you can manage a backup plan on the possibility of something going wrong.

The small extra added cost is well worth having a store doing the delivery.

Eventually if the firm is big enough, a local family store may be even more than happy than receiving an automated email asking for such stuff.

PS. I used such services in 2016 xmas, around a time of a surgery, and bought in a big super market chain pretty much all the food, cakes, drinks for xmas, 200 Euros of goods that were delivered at my door at an arranged day and hour. The extra cost of delivery was between 4 and 6 Euros, depending on the time of day.

Answer (score 1):

IF it is a recurring event, build rotating schedule consisting of ALL people in the team, that way no one would feel "special".
The volunteer could also get some money for "fuel" getting the cake